# C++ simple program - Why isn't my "res" going into my vector? Creating a program that takes input (4+44-67+235) and outputs the result

Tags: c++

I fixed the -'0' errors, and now my output somewhat relates to my input. I believe it's multiplying my first 'c' value by 10, and not the other ones. How would I obtain the correct value of a number like 143 to calculate into my output?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class token { 
    public: char kind;
            char value;
};

int main(){
    vector<token> vt;
    char c;
    token t;
    int res = 0;
    while (cin>>c){
        if(c!= '+' && c!= '-' && c!= '='){

            res = res*10+c-'0';
        }
        else {
            t.kind = c;
            t.value = res;

            vt.push_back(t);
            res = 0;

        }
        if (c=='=')
            break;
    }
    int num = vt[0].value-'0';
    for(int i=0; i<vt.size(); i++){
        if (vt[i].kind=='+')
            num+=vt[i+1].value-'0';
        if (vt[i].kind=='-')
            num-=vt[i+1].value-'0';
    }
    cout<<num;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: The initial value of `t` is indeterminate. You didn't initialize it when setting `res`.

Comment: c-'0' converts it to a digit which can be used in math

Comment: @CygnusX1: I missed that. Thanks, edited my comment.

Comment: @someguy, `t` is set before being used.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting the '0' when reading the input is enough, you don't have to subtract it again when iterating through the elements.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, the test data in the title won't give you the expected result because `235` is too big for a signed `char`, which goes between -128 and 127. You should choose an `int` instead to cover larger operands.

Comment: `unsigned char` is probably a bad choice - it will work for this case, but the OP seems to want to support negative numbers as well - even one of the temporary results here is negative.

Comment: True. I don't think negatives are the issue, since the `-` is parsed away. But it would be too small for the general case.

Answer (score 0):

You already converted your input to a number with `res = res * 10 - '0'` and then you do it again with `vt[0].value - '0'` and `vt[i].value - '0'` and that cause an invalid output

Comment: Thank you. Now there seems to be another logic error. The values are not getting multiplied right. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Substracting `'0'` in the last loop is first problem, you already substracted it in the first loop.

Another problem is, as others pointed out, that you should use other type for `token::value` 
(`int` or `unsigned char`). (If you store 235 in `char`, it will end up as -21...)

Lastly, you iterate the last loop `vt.size()` times and then using vt[i+1].value - so you are reading after the end of the vector. The loop should be only

```
for (int i=0; i<vt.size()-1;++i) {
```

Also, don't forget that your program requires the output to be terminated by `'='` (and it is not in the title of your question)

EDIT: I merged the edits into the code below. For input `4+44-67+235=` it yields result `216`. But you have to use the last `'='`, otherwise you're not storing the last value and the result will be `-19`.

```
using namespace std;
class token { 
public: 
    char kind;
    int value;
};

int main(){
vector<token> vt;
char c;
token t;
int res = 0;
while (cin>>c){
    if(c!= '+' && c!= '-' && c!= '='){
        res = res*10+c-'0'; 
    }
    else {
        t.kind = c;
        t.value = res;

        vt.push_back(t);
        res = 0;
    }
    if (c=='=')
        break; 
}

int num = vt[0].value;
    for(int i=0; i<vt.size()-1; i++){
        if (vt[i].kind=='+')
                    num+=vt[i+1].value;
        if (vt[i].kind=='-')
            num-=vt[i+1].value;
    }
cout<<num <<endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: I believe there is a problem in my res loop. I still don't seem to be getting the right output.

Comment: Your res loop seems fine. At least as long you end the input with `=`. See updated answer for the whole code. If you're not sure about the values that are stored in the vector, then simply print them right before/after you store them